# Can Cypher filter results based on an attribute of the first encountered node of a given type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I'm using Neo4J and learning Cypher, and have a question about filtering results based on an attribute of the first encountered node of a given type (in the `OPTIONAL MATCH` line of the example code below).

My query is as follows:

```
MATCH 
  (a:Word), 
  (b:Word)
WHERE a.lemma IN [ "enjoy" ]
  AND b.lemma IN [ "control", "achievement" ]
OPTIONAL MATCH p = shortestPath((a)-[:IS_DEFINED_AS|IS_A_FORM_OF*..15]-(b)) 
RETURN 
  a.lemma as From, b.lemma as To,
  length(
    filter(n in nodes(p) WHERE 'Word' in labels(n))
  ) - 1 as Shortest_Number_of_Hops_Only_Counting_Words, 
  length(p) as Shortest_Number_of_Hops_Counting_All_Nodes
```

Two general types of paths might occur in the database:

```
(a:Word) <-[IS_A_FORM_OF]- (Morph) -[IS_A_FORM_OF]-> (Word) -[IS_DEFINED_AS]-> (Synset) <-[IS_DEFINED_AS]- (Word) -[IS_DEFINED_AS]-> (Synset) <-[IS_DEFINED_AS]- (b:Word)
```

and

```
(a:Word) -[IS_DEFINED_AS]-> (Synset) <-[IS_DEFINED_AS]- (Word) -[IS_DEFINED_AS]-> (Synset) <-[IS_DEFINED_AS]- (b:Word)
```

There might be any number of hops (currently capped at 15 in the query above) between `a` and `b`.

I've tried to give a very specific example above, but my question really is a very general one about using Cypher: **I would like to filter for paths in which the first Synset node encountered contains a certain attribute (for example, `{part_of_speech: 'verb'}`.** I've been reading the [Cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) and am wondering whether the `head()` expression should be used to somehow select the first Synset node in the path, but I'm unsure how to do it. Is there a straightforward way to add this to the MATCH / WHERE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oleg-kurbatov's answer *does* work, but only if (a:Word) is immediately connected to a Synset (it doesn't account for instances where (a:Word) must travel through a node of type Morph, etc., before getting to a Synset (as in my first example path in the original question). Additionally, the adding-paths-together approach seems more computationally intensive – 802ms for my original query vs 2364ms using a slightly modified version of Oleg's suggested implementation (since Cypher/Neo4J doesn't allow specifying more than one specific hop when using `shortestPath()`:

```
MATCH 
  (a:Word),
  (b:Word)
WHERE a.lemma IN [ "enjoy" ]
  AND b.lemma IN [ "control", "achievement" ]
MATCH p1 = (a)-[:IS_DEFINED_AS]-> (initial_synset:Synset{pos: 'v'})
OPTIONAL MATCH p2 = shortestPath((initial_synset)-[:IS_DEFINED_AS|IS_A_FORM_OF*..15]-(b))
RETURN 
  a.lemma as From, b.lemma as To,
  length(
    filter(n in nodes(p2) WHERE 'Word' in labels(n))
  ) as Shortest_Number_of_Hops_Only_Counting_Words,
  length(p1) + length(p2) as Shortest_Number_of_Hops_Counting_All_Nodes
```

Taking Oleg's suggestion as a starting point, though, I did figure out one way to filter `shortestPath()` so that it only settles on a path where the first encountered Synset node has a 'pos' attribute of 'v', without increasing query execution time: I amended the `OPTIONAL MATCH` line in my original question to read:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p = shortestPath((a)-[:IS_DEFINED_AS|IS_A_FORM_OF*..15]-(b))
WHERE head(filter(x in nodes(p) WHERE x:Synset)).pos = 'v'
```

As I understand, `filter(x in nodes(p) WHERE x:Synset)` gets a list of all Synset-type nodes in the path being considered. `head(...)` gets the first node from that list, and `.pos = 'v'` checks that that node's "pos" attribute is "v".

Answer (score 0):

You can match Synset node by its property like this

```
MATCH (verb:Synset {part_of_speech: 'verb'})
RETURN verb
```

Then variable `verb` will match only Synset nodes whose `part_of_speech` property is `"verb"`.

You can use this variable further on in your request. For example you can write essentially the same request restricting the value of node's property in `WHERE` section:

```
MATCH (verb:Synset)
WHERE verb.part_of_speech = 'verb'
RETURN verb
```

Applying to your request you might rewrite it like this:

```
MATCH 
  (a:Word) -[:IS_DEFINED_AS]-> (verb:Synset {part_of_speech: "verb"}), 
  (b:Word)
WHERE a.lemma IN [ "enjoy" ]
  AND b.lemma IN [ "control", "achievement" ]
OPTIONAL MATCH p = shortestPath((a)-[:IS_DEFINED_AS]-(verb)-[:IS_DEFINED_AS|IS_A_FORM_OF*..15]-(b)) 
RETURN 
  a.lemma as From, b.lemma as To,
  length(
    filter(n in nodes(p) WHERE 'Word' in labels(n))
  ) - 1 as Shortest_Number_of_Hops_Only_Counting_Words, 
  length(p) as Shortest_Number_of_Hops_Counting_All_Nodes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! This got me much of the way toward constructing the answer that I came up with below. I didn't realize until reading your answer that it's possible to add paths together using Cypher. I'm grateful for your help : )